# Why does my program go into an infinite loop when the user types invalid input?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int input;
  do {
    printf("Welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz Program!\n\n");
    printf("Please choose one of the following by entering the correspoding "
           "number:\n\n");
    printf("1. Give me an addition problem.\n");
    printf("2. Give me a subtraction problem.\n");
    printf("3. Give me a multiplication problem.\n");
    printf("4. Quit.\n\n");

    scanf(" %i", &input);

  } while (input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && input != 4);
  return 0;
}
```

When I enter something that's not integer (ex: 'a','b',..), it turns out like this:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66264109/1229023) is particularly interesting.

Comment: `scanf` also returns the number of fields it read correctly, you should not ignore it.

Comment: A) C/C++ is not a language. You can only compile and run it as either C *or* C++. B) Please do not post screenshots of plain-text data. Copy-paste that into your question instead. It helps considerably when adapting your question into an answer.

Comment: What this really needs is `if (input == 4) break`.

Comment: I'm sorry for not making it clear but the loop went on forever and I couldn't copy it. What I entered is a input that's not integer (ex: char).